# JavaFX - Editable number cells don't work. J

Tags: java, javafx, types, casting

I have problem beause I can't save value from my cell. This is my column in Controller Class:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Instrument, Number> wagaCol;
```

In initialize method I write two things, to make editable Table cell:

```
wagaCol.setOnEditCommit(e->wagaCol_edycja(e));
wagaCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter()));
```

And now under initialize method I have created method 'wagaCol_edycja(e)' to save that field in attribute of different Class.

```
public void wagaCol_edycja(Event e) {
    TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Instrument, Long> cellEditEvent;
    cellEditEvent = (TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Instrument, Long>) e;
    Instrument instrument = cellEditEvent.getRowValue();
    instrument.setWaga(cellEditEvent.getNewValue().floatValue());
}
```

In this this method, setWaga returns float value. I want to save value of wagaCol and assigns this to setWaga. The problem is that i have error:

**Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long**

1. I don't know why my column returns type of Long. It should returns float type.
2. I can save only integer values. When i type for instance 8.453 it gaves me an error.

Comment: If you want float value then change the type of column from `number` to `Double` and then see what happens

Comment: Your cellEditEvent is define to Long change it to Number

Comment: Thank you, now it works fine :)

Comment: @JackyBBB what did you changed that now is working?